# Wordpress Menus apearing twice in computer version

Tags: caching, menu

I'm facing an issue with my website where it displays two menus in the computer version, seemingly due to a cache-related problem. I've attached a screenshot for reference [Insert Screenshot Link].

I've tried several solutions like clearing the browser cache and even purging the website cache on my hosting, but the problem persists. The mobile version and other elements of the site appear to be working fine.[showing two menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQwWw.jpg)

You check this link [from here](https://www.dz-techs.com/fix-open-with-not-working-windows10).

Thanks,

clearing the browser cache and even purging the website cache on my hosting.